# multiheritance in C++, different files : "Expected class-name before ',' token"

Tags: c++

I am getting this error "Expected class-name before ',' token" and "Expected class-name before '{' token" in MainController.h
I think I am including files as needed, also doing #ifndef HEADER_H #define HEADER_H, etc in all headers, I had no errors until I wrote MainController class. 
I have no idea why this error appears. What am I missing here?

I have N4GestureRecognizer.h:

```
class N4GestureRecognizer;
class N4GestureRecognizerDataSource{ /*it uses N4GestureRecognizer*/ };
class N4GestureRecognizerDelegate{    };
class N4GestureRecognizer {
...    
};
```

N4FingerTipGestureRecognizer.h

```
#include "N4GestureRecognizer.h"
class N4FingerTipGestureRecognizer;

class N4FingerTipGestureRecognizerDelegate : public N4GestureRecognizerDelegate{
public:
    virtual void fingerTipGestureRecognizerCallback(N4FingerTipGestureRecognizer *recognizer) = 0;
};
class N4FingerTipGestureRecognizer : public N4GestureRecognizer{
...    
};
```

And MainController.h

```
#include "N4GestureRecognizer.h"
#include "N4FingerTipGestureRecognizer.h"

using namespace cv;

//******Error is in the next line******
class MainController : public N4GestureRecognizerDatasource, public N4FingerTipGestureRecognizeDelegate{ 
protected:
    Mat image;
public:
    /*virtual*/ Mat gestureRecognizerNeedsImageFrame(N4GestureRecognizer *recognizer);
    /*virtual*/ void fingerTipGestureRecognizerCallback(N4FingerTipGestureRecognizer *recognizer);

};
```

Comment: You're not *literally* writing `#ifndef HEADER_H`, are you? The macro name needs to be different for each header.

Comment: Don't write `using namespace` in header files; and please try to post real, working code: neither namespace `cv` nor type `Mat` are declared in your code and cause additional compilation errors that are not related to the problem.

Comment: Why I should not write "using namespace" in headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be two typos in your code:

1. In `N4GestureRecognizer.h` you have `N4GestureRecognizerDataSource`, but you try have `MainController` inherit from `N4GestureRecognizerDatasource`; note the different case of the `S` in `DataSource`.
2. In `N4FingerTipGestureRecognizer.h` you have `N4FingerTipGestureRecognizerDelegate`, but you try to have `MainController` inherit from `N4FingerTipGestureRecognizeDelegate`; note the missing `r` before `Delegate`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the source you have pasted above is really the text your source contains the problem is in `class N4GestureRecognizerDataSource` versus `public N4GestureRecognizerDatasource`.